# WordPress iOS API

Tags: ios, wordpress

I would like to know if there is an API for WordPress, built in Objective-C for iOS. This API must support the following:

- It must support custom servers (e.g. www.myblog.com, instead of myblog.wordpress.com).
- It must allow me to make a post to the blog, and let me save a post as a draft.
- It preferably would be simple to set up, I simply authenticate the user, and have access to what I would want, similar to this

```
WordPress *wp = [[WordPress alloc] initWithServer:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myblog.com"];
[wp authenticate:@"wordpress-user-name" password:@"wordpress-user-password"];
[wp saveDraft:@"wordpress-post-name" content:@"wordpress-post-content" tags:@"wordpress-post-tags"];
[wp postDraft:@"wordpress-post-name"];
[wp logout];
[wp release];
```

If there is no such API out there, can anyone point me to some references that could help me get started on writing my own?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the Wordpress iOS app: http://ios.wordpress.org/. It includes the necessary XML-RPC libraries.

EDIT: it uses the XML-RPC interface, of which there are a number of, including https://bitbucket.org/kdbdallas/xmlrpc-ios

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use this? The WordPress API Documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp didn't tell me how to invoke this stuff.

Comment: If you look at http://ios.trac.wordpress.org/browser#trunk, you will actually see the source for the Wordpress iOS app. This includes all the examples you could need that cover actually calling the Wordpress API using XML-RPC. For a more detailed breakdown look at http://www.leoganda.net/xml-rpc-on-iphone/

Comment: @Femi Broken leoganda.net link? (I'm getting 404). Thanks.